# Auto add 'this' identifier when auto completing in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I use a custom set of rules in [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) along with it's ReSharper plugin to automatically check my code as I type.

The rule [SA1101](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1101.html) in StyleCop states that calls to members of the current class need to begin with `this.` to indicate that it is in-fact defined in the current class.

Is there a way to set it up so when I go to auto-complete a member of the class, it automatically adds in the `this.` prefix, so I don't have to remember how to type it or add it afterwards?

Lets use `public bool Running { get; set; }` as an example:

I type "`Run`" + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and right now it comes out to `Running`, but I would like it to come out as `this.Running`.

This would save a-lot of time and typing.

**EDIT**

Please note that the option `ReSharper => Options => Code Editing => C# => Formatting Style => Other => "Force 'this.' qualifier for instance member"` (as mentioned by Jon) in resharper does not work as intended. Neither when adding a `;` at the end of the statement (which would be acceptable), or after the tab is `this.` being added to the class member.

Comment: Is this a rule that is applicable to your coding style?  The only reason I can think of for always qualifying members with `this` is to avoid name collisions with method parameters, i.e., you have a backing field `name` and a method parameter `name`.  However, ff your style for member variables is something like `_name` then using `this` all over the place only clutters the code IMO.

Comment: Not trying to be a smartass, but it'd probably save you time if you went through and added the prefixes yourself.

Comment: @EdS.: Notice that the rule is applicable to members of the *current* class, not members of any of its bases. So it does provide some level of information if you use and omit it consistently.

Comment: @Jon: Consistency is always good, yes, but what purpose does it serve other than that which I previously mentioned?  Does it *really* help you to know that if you see `this` then the member was defined in the current class?  I just don't see that as useful, especially with Visual Studio making it ridiculously simply to track your code and find where things are defined and overriden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to

```
ReSharper => Options => Code Editing => C# => Formatting Style => Other
```

there is an option called *"Force 'this.' qualifier for instance member"*.

Enabling it should work as you intend.

Comment: Tried it, when either adding a `;` at the end of my statement, or after tab, it does not update.